# getting css errors with tomcat7 java7

Tags: css

When start my application on Firefox, I get these errors: [image]

I m using java 7 and tomcat 7.
I didn't have such problems when I was using: java 5 and tomcat6.

need help please

Answer (score 0):

You probably have errors in your stylesheets (maybe because they are processed by the server). On the right you should have a reference link to the stylesheet and the line the error comes from.